# How to write formulas/maths expressions in the forum?

Tags: support

I'm new to this forum, I was wondering how to write neat formulas in the post/question?
Do I have to use MathXML and code everything in XML or is there an editor?

Comment: First of all this is not a forum, it is a **physics** question and answer site that uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) for equation rendering. If you know LaTeX it is basically just that. Put it in \$ \$ for inline or \$\$ \$\$ for block mode.

Comment: ***My standard reply:*** Note that MathJax is supported here. Use it to render equations. If you are not familiar with MathJax, it is essentially LaTeX code (but it ***must*** be surrounded by `$` signs for inline equations and `$$` signs for other equations. E.g. `$$E=\sum_{j=1}mc^3$$` results in $$E=\sum_{j=1}mc^3$$ and `$E=\sum_{j=1}mc^3` results in $E=\sum_{j=1}mc^3$. For a documentation of LaTeX, see [LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).. P.S. I understand that you don't have enough rep (5 rep) to particiipate in [meta], but once you do, please post such questions the(contd.)

Comment: thanks, didn't mean to be rude by defining the site as a forum

Comment: (contd.)re instead.    For now, I'm just flagging this post for  migration to meta.

Comment: @Luther No worries. It wasn't rude, just inaccurate ;) Also it was off-topic on the main site, but is perfectly okay now that it's on meta.